# I have trouble with telegram.ext.filters has not have attribute "text"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I'm working on python-telegram-bot v13.7 and module telegram.ext.filters has not have attribute "text"
this is code:

```
import logging
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
import telegram.ext.filters as Filters
import openai
import urllib3


openai.api_key = 'token openai'

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text('Hi I'm your personal bot')

def echo(update, context):
    user_input = update.message.text
    response = generate_response(user_input)
    update.message.reply_text(response)

def generate_response(input_text):
    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="text-davinci-002",
        prompt=input_text,
        max_tokens=50
    )
    return response.choices[0].text.strip()

def main():
    updater = Updater("token telegram", use_context=True )

    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

    dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))

    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, echo))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tried Filters.text and filters.Text too
I tried to know is telegram.ext.filters has "text" and it is what I see[there is no "text" attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC9p9.png) then I tried reinstall, upgrade and downgrade but nothing new
so how it can be fixed?

```
 D:\R.M\Python\Lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py:49: UserWarning: python-telegram-bot is using upstream urllib3. This is allowed but not supported by python-telegram-bot maintainers.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\R.M\piton\CHATGPTTELEGRAM.PY", line 13, in <module>
    do_stuff()
  File "D:\R.M\piton\CHATGPTTELEGRAM.PY", line 10, in do_stuff
    raise Exception("test exception")
Exception: test exception

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\R.M\piton\CHATGPTTELEGRAM.PY", line 64, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\R.M\piton\CHATGPTTELEGRAM.PY", line 55, in main
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, echo))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'telegram.ext.filters' has no attribute 'TEXT'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Please do not share images, post the error in the code format

Answer (score 0):

You have installed version 13.7 of `python-telegram-bot` but are using the `filters` module like you had installed version 20 or newer. The v13.7 documentation of the `filters` module is available [here](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v13.7/telegram.ext.filters.html). Please note that the PTB team no longer provides support for versions older than v20 and I encourage you to update to the latest version using the [transition guide](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Transition-guide-to-Version-20.0).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.